# Hard time understanding the use of if and in when creating a new dictionary/list

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I don't understand how the code below works. How is it possible to have something "in" `reviews_max` if it's an empty dictionary?

```
reviews_max = {}

for app in android:
    name = app[0]
    n_reviews = float(app[3])

    if name in reviews_max and reviews_max[name] < n_reviews:
        reviews_max[name] = n_reviews

    elif name not in reviews_max:
        reviews_max[name] = n_reviews
```

Comment: After the first iteration, it's not empty any more.

Comment: the key thing to understand with a code like this is to ask what happens as the iterations continue beyond the first pass.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at it block by block:

```
# define an empty dictionary called `reviews_max`
reviews_max = {}

# for each entry in the list `android`, store the name and number of reviews
for app in android:
    name = app[0]
    n_reviews = float(app[3])

    # if there's already an entry in `reviews_max` for that app,
    # and the value of that entry is smaller than the number of reviews for the app,
    # update the entry
    if name in reviews_max and reviews_max[name] < n_reviews:
            reviews_max[name] = n_reviews

    # otherwise, add the entry to reviews_max
    elif name not in reviews_max:
            reviews_max[name] = n_reviews
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't be empty after the first iteration, since this line is run:

```
reviews_max[name] = n_reviews
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that on the first iteration, `reviews_max` will be empty. But if `android` contains more than one element, `reviews_max` will not be empty, because `app[0]` will be added to it as a key for `app[3]` on the first iteration

This code:

```
reviews_max[name] = n_reviews
```

assigns `name`, defined as `app[0]`, to `n_reviews`, defined as `float(app[3])` in `the reviews_max` dictionary on the first iteration because `name` is not in `reviews_max`.